# How to find stopped job executions in spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

What is the best practice to find stopped job executions in order to restart them in spring batch ?

We have an application that reads large amount of files and processes them, currently I have configured a shutdownhook that stopps an job execution when the application is stopped using a kill signal.

The next step that I have to do is, after application context is loaded I have to restart all stopped jobs, so my question is what is the best way to do so ?
Is there any alternative for finding stopped job executions ?

The code I have now is:

```
public class JobRestarterLauncher implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
@Autowired
private JobRestarter jobRestarter;
@Autowired
private JobExecutionDao jobExecutionDaoJdbcImpl;

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    logger.info("Restarting stopped jobs");
    List<Long> stoppedJobExecutionIds = jobExecutionDaoJdbcImpl.getStoppedJobExecutionIds();
    for (Long stoppedJobExecutionId : stoppedJobExecutionIds) {
        try
        {
            jobRestarter.restartJob(stoppedJobExecutionId);
        }catch(Exception exception){
            logger.error("Failed to start jobExectionId [" + stoppedJobExecutionId + "]", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class JobRestarter {
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
@Autowired
private JobOperator jobOperator;

@Transactional
public void restartJob(Long executionId) {
    try {
        Long restartExecutionId = jobOperator.restart(executionId);
        logger.info("Restarted job with executionId [" + restartExecutionId + "]");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error("Failed to restart job with executionId [" + executionId + "]", exception);
    }
}
```

}

While jobExecutionDaoJdbcImpl finds the last job execution ids from the spring batch metadata tables with the next query:

[image: query]